# Extend a pandas dataframe to include 'missing' weeks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which contains time series data, so the index of the dataframe is of type datetime64 at weekly intervals, each date occurs on the Monday of each calendar week.

There are only entries in the dataframe when an order was recorded, so if there was no order placed, there isn't a corresponding record in the dataframe.  I would like to "pad" this dataframe so that any weeks in a given date range are included in the dataframe and a corresponding zero quantity is entered.

I have managed to get this working by creating a dummy dataframe, which includes an entry for each week that I want with a zero quantity and then merging these two dataframes and dropping the dummy dataframe column.  This results in a 3rd padded dataframe.

I don't feel this is a great solution to the problem and being new to pandas wanted to know if there is a more specific and or pythonic way to achieve this, probably without having to create a dummy dataframe and then merge.

The code I used is below to get my current solution:

```
# Create the dummy product
# Week hold the week date of the order, want to set this as index later
group_by_product_name = df_all_products.groupby(['Week', 'Product Name'])['Qty'].sum()
first_date = group_by_product_name.head(1) # First date in entire dataset
last_date = group_by_product_name.tail().index[-1] # last date in the data set
bdates = pd.bdate_range(start=first_date, end=last_date, freq='W-MON')
qty = np.zeros(bdates.shape)
dummy_product = {'Week':bdates, 'DummyQty':qty}
df_dummy_product = pd.DataFrame(dummy_product)
df_dummy_product.set_index('Week', inplace=True)


group_by_product_name = df_all_products.groupby('Week')['Qty'].sum()
df_temp = pd.concat([df_dummy_product, group_by_product_name], axis=1, join='outer')
df_temp.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_temp.drop(columns=['DummyQty'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The problem with this approach is sometimes (I don't know why) the indexes don't match correctly, I think somehow the dtype of the index on one of the dataframes loses its type and goes to object instead of staying with dtype datetime64.  So I am sure there is a better way to solve this problem than my current solution.

EDIT

Here is a sample dataframe with "missing entries"

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Week':['2018-05-28', '2018-06-04',
   '2018-06-11', '2018-06-25'], 'Qty':[100, 200, 300, 500]})
df1.set_index('Week', inplace=True)
df1.head()
```

Here is an example of the padded dataframe that contains the additional missing dates between the date range

```
 df_zero = pd.DataFrame({'Week':['2018-05-21', '2018-05-28', '2018-06-04',
   '2018-06-11', '2018-06-18', '2018-06-25', '2018-07-02'], 'Dummy Qty':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
df_zero.set_index('Week', inplace=True)
df_zero.head()
```

And this is the intended outcome after concatenating the two dataframes

```
df_padded = pd.concat([df_zero, df1], axis=1, join='outer')
df_padded.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_padded.drop(columns=['Dummy Qty'], inplace=True)
df_padded.head(6)
```

Note that the missing entries are added before and between other entries where necessary in the final dataframe.

Edit 2:

As requested here is an example of what the initial product dataframe would look like:

```
df_all_products = pd.DataFrame({'Week':['2018-05-21', '2018-05-28', '2018-05-21', '2018-06-11', '2018-06-18',
   '2018-06-25', '2018-07-02'], 
                            'Product Name':['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 
                            'Qty':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]})
```

Comment: I think there's a better way of doing this. Can you include a sample of your data please - with expected output given the sample data.

Comment: Sure, I have added an example now with two dataframes and the final merged result

Comment: ok so the first entry in `df1` is not necessarily the start_date. You actually want to fill it from `2018-05-21` to `2018-07-02`? Wouldn't it be sufficient to add the missing weeks in `df1` between the date range of first date and last date in the data provided in `df1`? so in this case it will only add `2018-06-18`

Comment: You can do that by using resample: `df1.resample('W-MON').asfreq().fillna(0)`

Comment: Wow nice thanks for that, it's much simpler.  It would be ideal to pad over a whole given date range, but at least for the inbetween padding this is a very simple solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Np.. it might be possible. Where do you get the whole date range from ? df_all_products ?

Comment: Yes.  so the goal would be to have all the time series for the products all the same length.  So I just take the first date entry in it and the last, to decide this time range.

Comment: I see. I think it can be done in a better way tbh. Can you provide a sample of `df_all_products` please?

Comment: I added an example to the original question.  So the end result should be two separate dataframes for each product with their own Qty entries but the same date entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok given your original data you can achieve the expected results by using `pivot` and resample for any missing weeks, like the following:

```
results = df_all_products.groupby(
    ['Week','Product Name']
)['Qty'].sum().reset_index().pivot(
    index='Week',columns='Product Name', values='Qty'
).resample('W-MON').asfreq().fillna(0)
```

Output results:

```
Product Name    A   B
Week        
2018-05-21  100.0   300.0
2018-05-28  200.0   0.0
2018-06-04  0.0     0.0
2018-06-11  400.0   0.0
2018-06-18  0.0     500.0
2018-06-25  600.0   0.0
2018-07-02  700.0   0.0
```

So if you want to get the `df` for Product Name A, you can do `results['A']`.